# Delay build function until initialization, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, provider

In the **initState()** of my StatefulWidget, I am calling a function called ***initializeNewGrid()***:

```
void initState() {
  // get abbacus provider
  abbacusProvider = Provider.of<AbbacusProvider>(context, listen: false);
  // initialize new abbacus
  abbacusProvider.initializeNewGrid(reset: false);
}
```

This function calls some more functions for initialization of the needed variables, one of these functions which has a return type of **int** is performing a lot of computations:

```
int generateProblem({required bool next}) {
  //
  // Code to generate a new problem
  //

  // return solution of the generated problem
  return computeCorrectSolution();
}
```

such that when **build()** method is called the computation is not yet completed, and some of the lists that are not yet filled with data are tried to be accessed with the **ListView.builder**, which results in the following error:

```
The following RangeError was thrown building: I/flutter (23729): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

I have tried using **Future** but haven't been able to do it properly. The build always executes before the complete initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your initState as mentioned below

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      // get abbacus provider
      abbacusProvider = Provider.of<AbbacusProvider>(context, listen: false);
      // initialize new abbacus
      abbacusProvider.initializeNewGrid(reset: false);
    });
  }
```